# TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined in Jest

Tags: typescript, jestjs

My test case is failing, saying  `TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined`. This is what I am doing in code  -

```
act(() => {
        wrapper
            .find(ComponentA)
            .first()
            .find(RadioButton)
            .first()
            .props()
            .onChange('first', {id:'first' , isChecked: true });
    });
```

in this code I am getting error, says `id is undefined`. When I am consoling the code like -

```
console.log(wrapper
        .find(ComponentA)
        .first()
        .find(RadioButton)
        .first()
        .props(), "console")
```

Then I am getting following output -

```
{
        id: 'first',
        isChecked: true,
        onChange: [Function: onChange],
        radioFontSize: '1.43rem',
        labelFontSize: '1rem',
        radioColor: 'rgb(9, 114, 142)',
        labelColor: 'rgb(48, 46, 44)'
      } console
```

If I am getting `id` in console then why it is saying undefined `id` ? I have written this test case in jest. Can someone help me in that ?

Comment: Probably it would be a good idea to post the code that causes the `Cannot read property 'id' of undefined` error

Comment: @Teneff, it is definitely good idea)

Comment: @Teneff So big code. Not possible to paste it here. Can we discuss somewhere else ?

Comment: @Teneff I have setup the code - `https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-hooks-e99zt?file=/src/ModalComponent.spec.tsx`. Please go through it. I am getting error just spec file for unit testing.